# Geometric interpretation of a critical point, i.e. of $q(t) := f(x + t(y-x))$.

Tags: functions, optimization

So, I know what critical points are. But hear me out on the following notes I made:

For $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we define $$q(t) := f(x + t(y-x)), $$ then $$q'(t)=\nabla f(x+t(y-x))^T(y-x).$$

Now, if $x$ is a minimum of $f$, then $q$ has a minimum at $t=0$, and so $q'(0)=0$, i.e. $\nabla f(x)^T(y-x) = 0$. Since this should hold for all $y$, we *necessarily* have $\nabla f(x)=0$.

Such an $x$ is called a critical point or stationary point.

**So...** Whats with the $q(t)$? What is the geometric equivalent of this reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$q$ evaluated the values of $f$ along the (linear parametrisized) line from $x$ to $y$.